# Exporting SQL Query to Excel with Username/Password

Tags: sql, excel

I am new to this but trying to get it worked out, hoping to find some advice here.

My setup:
Excel 2016 64 Bit
SQL Server 2014 Import and Export Data (64-Bit)
Windows 7 64 Bit
Windows PowerShell ISE (x86)
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server

I can export my SQL database perfectly into excel, now I'm just trying to automate it. Here is the code I am currently using:

PowerShell lines

```
$serverName = "E2\E2SQL";
$databaseName = "*****";
$uid ="*****"
$pwd = "*****"
#the save location for the new Excel file
$filepath = "C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\TEST.xls";
#create a Dataset to store the DataTable 
$dataSet = new-object "System.Data.DataSet" "TEST"
#create a Connection to the SQL Server database
$cn = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection "server=$serverName;database=$databaseName;Integrated Security=false; User ID = $uid; Password = $pwd;"
$query= "SELECT JobNo FROM Online;"
#Create a SQL Data Adapter to place the resultset into the DataSet
$dataAdapter = new-object "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter" ($query, $cn)
$dataAdapter.Fill($dataSet) | Out-Null
#close the connection
$cn.Close()
```

I get an error on
$dataSet = new-object "System.Data.DataSet" "TEST"

I don't really understand that line of code... Anyway any thoughts on how to get this working are greatly appreciated!

I would also be open to exporting to a CSV if that makes it easier.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Try without the quotes on that line.

Comment: It looks like you are filling the dataset, but not outputting the results.

Comment: Tried removing quotes, did not help. My error is as follows:

Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.
At C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\test\SQL1.ps1:32 char:2
+ } <<<< 
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (}:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

Comment: Also, I have code to export, just had it turned off for the time being, it is as follows:

$dataTable = new-object "System.Data.DataTable" "TEST"
$dataTable = $dataSet.Tables[0]